# Not able to alter table character set encoding from latin1_swedish_ci to utf8mb4_bin

Tags: mysql

Trying alter table through this query

```
 ALTER TABLE `outlooks` CHANGE `description` `description` TEXT    CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

but getting error

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL' at line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not the right syntax. The error is pretty clear about where the problem is, too.

According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) it should look like:

```
ALTER TABLE `outlooks`
CHANGE `description`
`description` TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

However this won't convert the content of the data table from ISO-8859-1 to UTF8. You're probably [looking for](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE `outlooks` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```